# Vert.x make a promise from vertx.executeBlocking

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x

I have four I/O operations: `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Each of them should be executed with `vertx.executeBlocking`. I should have the next behaviour:

```
//PSEUDOCODE
waitForExecuteBlocking(A_OPERATION);
thenWaitForAllExecuteBlocking(`B_OPERATION`, `C_OPERATION`, `D_OPERATION`)
/* do something */
```

*How can I achieve this behaviour?*

I can't find the solutioin in [Vertx Rx](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java/). There are reasons why I don't want to wrap my `*_OPERATION` classes as worker verticles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding another answer, this time with Futures.
First of all please note, that those are Vertx futures, not regular Java futures. Use the correct import.
Now to the code:

```
// I'm running in main(), so everything is static, just for the sake of example
private static Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // In your case it should be operationA(), operationB(), etc
    // But I wanted to make the code shorter
    CompositeFuture.all(operationA(), operationA(), operationA()).setHandler((r) -> {
        if (r.succeeded()) {
            // You can even iterate all the results
            List<String> results = r.result().list();
            for (String result : results) {
                System.out.println(result);
            }
            // This will still print max(operationA, operationB, operationC)
            System.out.println("Took me " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " millis");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
    });
}


// Return a future, then fulfill it after some time
private static Future<String> operationA() {
    Future<String> future = Future.future();

    long millis = 1000 + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(500);
    vertx.setTimer(millis, (l) -> {
        future.complete("All is good " + millis);
    });

    return future;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll break my answer into two. It won't depend on RxJava, but on regular Java only.
First, to wait for A_OPERATION

```
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {

        @Override
        public void start() throws InterruptedException {
            // Just to demonstrate
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            latch.countDown();
        }
    });

    // Always use await with timeout
    latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println("Took me " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " millis");
```

Now to a more complex example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    // This should be equal to number of operations to complete
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Start your operations
    vertx.deployVerticle(new BlockingVerticle(latch));
    vertx.deployVerticle(new BlockingVerticle(latch));
    vertx.deployVerticle(new BlockingVerticle(latch));

    // Always use await with timeout
    latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println("Took me " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " millis");
}


private static class BlockingVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private final CountDownLatch latch;

    public BlockingVerticle(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws InterruptedException {


        long millis = 1000 + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(500);

        System.out.println("It will take me " + millis + " to complete");

        // Wait for some random time, but no longer that 1.5 seconds
        Thread.sleep(millis);

        latch.countDown();
    }

}
```

You should note that main thread will be blocked for max(B_OPERATION, C_OPERATION, D_OPERATION) + a few millis more.

Comment: thank you for answer! But that seems strange for me to deploy extra verticles in sake of synchronization. I also don't want to deploy them since my app is running with `-ha` options which mean little overhead for each verticle. As a solution (which I also dislike) I can use pass `CountDownLatch` inside `vertx.executeBlocking`. But vertx docs say that vertx is supposed to free yourseft from sync code, and that seems to be a wrong way

Comment: First of all, you're absolutely right. I thought that you had some specific reason that you wanted a blocking code. I'll add another answer with same code based on Futures.

Answer (score 0):

Using Composite Futures will help to solve your problem , there are many compositeFutures functions as compositeFuture.Join and compositeFutures.all , the list of futures can be passed